# POSIX locale, UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, docker, unicode

Open a docker instance (e.g., `docker run -ti ubuntu:16.04`), create the Python files `a.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a = 'ö'
```

and `r.py`

```
with open('a.py') as f: exec(f.read())
```

When executing `python r.py`, all is file. When using `python3`, however, one gets the dreaded

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "r.py", line 2, in <module>
    exec(f.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Curiously, I can reproduce this *only on docker*.

Any hints on what may be going wrong, and how to fix it? (Note that I can only modify `r.py`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between inside docker and outside of docker is likely the `LANG` environment variable -- many many base images default to no `LANG` set (or `LANG=C`, etc.).  Setting an explicit `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` will cause `open` to properly decode the source (in python 3)).  If you want the python 3 behavior in python2, you can `import io` and use `io.open`.

`exec` in python2 / python3 also allows `bytes`.

One way to avoid the encoding problem is to read the source from disk as bytes:

```
with open('a.py', 'rb') as f:
    exec(f.read())
```

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that with python3 and `a = {}; with open('a.py', 'rb') as f: exec(f.read(), a)` (to store `a.py`'s contents in a dict), this gives the error `ERROR - failed to write data to stream: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='ANSI_X3.4-1968'>`. Fixed with setting the environment variable `export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`.

Answer (score 2):

Starting docker with a UTF-8 locale makes it all work as expected

```
docker run -e LANG=C.UTF-8 -ti ubuntu:16.04
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `io`?

```
with io.open('a.py', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    do stuff
```

Comment: Works with `python3`, fails with `python`: `SyntaxError: encoding declaration in Unicode string`.